# What does my argument need to be in my java program?

Tags: java

I created a random array called "array". The amount of random integers and the range in which the random numbers are allowed to be generated from are both decided by whatever the user enters. At the end of the program it should say the maximum and minimum numbers in the array and some other things. So my teacher is having us use methods to accomplish this. I have a method called getMax and this is what is written in that method:

```
public static int getMax(int[] array){
     int max = 0;
     for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
         if(array[i] > max)
             max = array[i];
         return max;
     }
}
```

So my question is in MAIN. I need to return the max value to main so that it can display that. I understand that I need an integer variable that will accept it. So in main, I have a variable called biggest, so I wrote:

```
biggest = getMax();
```

What do I have to write in those parentheses above to make this work? What does the argument have to be? THANKS!

Comment: It should be an array of ints.

Comment: also you appear to have a Bug in the function, consider the position of `return max;`

Comment: Plus your logic is a bit wrong. It will consider the first element of the array the biggest. Put that `return max;` outside the for statement.

Comment: I have the array already created in main

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getMax(int[] array)
                         ^  ^
                         |  |
                         |  Array of int
                         |____________|
```

You need to pass an *array* of `int`s. For quick test, you can just:

```
System.out.println(getMax(new int[]{9,2,3,7}));
```

If you already have an array, say `numArray`, you can simply `getMax(numArray)`.

As others already mentioned in the comment, you seem to have a bug in your code, debug it to figure out what's wrong (reconsider your blocks).

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the array which has random values according to user needs !

```
int a[100];
//accept code and do whatever stuff
biggest = getMax(a);  //pass array
```

secondly the code should be :

```
public static int getMax(int[] array){
     int max = 0;
     for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
     if(array[i] > max)
     max = array[i];
     }
     return max;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do it. To make it work from the main class, you need to initialize an Integer array and passed it to your method.

You need to modify your code

```
    biggest = getMax();
```

to

```
    biggest = getMax(new int[]{1,2,5,10,9,7,6});
```

or if you want to have use a variable and then just pass it to the method you need to declare an integer array

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    //initialize an array variable named iArray
    int iArray [] = new int []{1,2,5,10,9,7,6};
    //Pass the iArray to the method
    int biggest = getMax(iArray);
}
```